# Geb $ function not found when using Cucumber via Cuke4Duke

Tags: testing, cucumber, integration

I'm using Cuke4Duke to run my Cucumber tests. I'm using Geb ([Geb Manual](http://geb.codehaus.org/manual/latest/index.html)) to control the browser.

Does anyone know how to configure Cucumber/Geb so that the $ function ([Geb $ Function](http://geb.codehaus.org/manual/latest/navigator.html#the__function)) is available to Cucumber tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser.$() seems to work fine. would be nice not to have to type browser though.